# SHRT_MIN in C as hex

Tags: c, hex, printf, short, integer-promotion

I wanted to display the highest and lowest "short" values as hexadecimal numbers (using a Windows environment, mingw64 compiler):

```
printf("largest %x and smallest %x",SHRT_MAX,SHRT_MIN)
```

The output was as expecteded for the max number -> 7fff
but for the min number the result is -> ffff 8000

Does anyone know why the min number is shown as a 4 byte number.

Thanks for your help,
Bert

Comment: `"%x"` expects an unsigned int, `SHRT_MIN` has type int. Try `printf("largest %d and smallest %d\n", SHRT_MAX, SHRT_MIN)` or `printf("largest %x and smallest -%x\n", SHRT_MAX, (unsigned)-SHRT_MIN)`

Comment: Use `%hx` instead, to say that the value is a `short`.

Comment: `%hx` would be appropriate for `SHRT_MAX`, but still non-conforming for `SHRT_MIN`, because of the signedness mismatch.  One could combine that with a cast to `unsigned short` -- that conforms, and it will yield the (presumable) expected result on two's complement systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. The %hx formatting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "largest %#hx and smallest %#hx\n", SHRT_MAX, SHRT_MIN );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
largest 0x7fff and smallest 0x8000
```

That is you need to use the length modifier `h`. Otherwise due to the integer promotions the values are outputted as objects of the type `int`.

Comment: In the comments the point was made that `%hx` is non-conforming for `SHRT_MIN`.  Is that not so?  (I think the purpose of the `#` specifier is to affect an _alternate form_, but has no other effect.)

Comment: @ryyker It is a hex representation. Neither sign is used.